# Combining Private Sub Worksheet_change excel

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you're doing. I am struggling with combining two Private Sub Worksheet_change(byval Target As Range) on excel. I would really appreciate if you help me combine these two codes.

I am kinda new to excel vba world so your input would be a big help for me

### Code 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xPTable As PivotTable
    Dim xPFile As PivotField
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
   
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B3:F3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xPTable = Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("Program2")
    xStr = Range("B3").Value
    xPFile.ClearAllFilters
    xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Intersect(Target, Range("B3:F3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xPTable = Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("ProgramType2")
    xStr = Range("C3").Value
    xPFile.ClearAllFilters
    xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

### Code 2

```
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
            Else:
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
            End If
        End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help a lot, if you'd describe what you want to achieve with this code.  Reading [Ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Well I want to make multi selection drop down list on excel with the second code whereas thr first one is to filter pivot table with cell reference

Comment: Then create two subs - one called `filterPivotTable` and a second one `createMultiSelectionDropDownList` with the according code. Then in the worksheet_change-event call one of both based on the changed cell.

Comment: I don't understand. Excel doesn't allow two Private Sub Worksheet_change(byval Target As Range) in a worksheet.

Comment: That's correct: so within this change-event you decide which of the two new subs are called - most likely based on the cell that was changed. Like e.g. `if target.address = "$c$3" then createMulitSelectionDropDownList else filterPivotTable end if`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I want both of the codes to be applied at the same time.

Comment: Then call both subs

Comment: I am really sorry I am new to the vba world. How can I call them subs?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    UpdatePivots Target
    MultiSelect Target
End Sub
    
Sub UpdatePivots(Target As Range)
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B3:F3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
   
    With Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
        With .PivotFields("Program2")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .CurrentPage = Range("B3").Value
        End With
        With .PivotFields("ProgramType2")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .CurrentPage = Range("C3").Value
        End With
   End With
End Sub

Sub MultiSelect(Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address(False, False) <> "C3" Then Exit Sub
    If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Not HasValidationList(Target) Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
    If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
    Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
        End If
    End If
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'does a ell have a validation list configured?
Function HasValidationList(c As Range) As Boolean
    Dim t As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    t = c.Validation.Type
    HasValidationList = (t = xlValidateList)
End Function
```